# Determining distance from drainage point to wildfire shapefiles using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-pro, proximity

I am having some trouble on how to calculate the wildfire distance from the nearest drainage in respect to nearby lakes (images provided). My research involves observing the water quality of multiple lakes post-wildfire, so I am trying to determine a way of calculating the distance of drainage to wildfire in order to relate to see possible inlets from nearby wildfires. I have the wildfire shapefile (shown in red) with the drainage in green (I am using HUC 12) and the respective lake in light blue.

[image]
I am having some trouble in associating this relationship, since many of the delineated watersheds do not directly overlap many of the lakes of interest (in the image provided it does overlap in the left section). I cannot get the Euclidean distance of fire and lake because for my analysis this would not be so helpful, so I am trying to see what the best approach would be.

Not shown in the picture, I do have a DEM of the area of interest since I knew that using the "Calculate Flow Distance" might help me for this scenario (even though I was not sure to do for the raster streams - I suppose I would have to use another dataset?). I also was looking into the "Flow Accumulation" function that might tell me where there drainages are, but again I am not entirely sure.

I am trying to work this processing in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: If you are also trying to do this using R then please ask about that in a new question.

Comment: Run set of hydrology tools on elevation model: fill  flow direction, flow distance - horizontal to raster representation of lakes. Compute any statistics required, e.g. minimum for fire polygons over flow distance.